Ubuntu 24.04 cannot install HP ENVY 6000 printer
I'm trying to install HP Envy 6000 printer, but at the end I get the following error:
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-devel (CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-image (CUPS image - CUPS image development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libusb (libusb - USB library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-devel (Python devel - Python development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libnetsnmp-devel (libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libcrypto (libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: python3-pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))
warning: This installer cannot install 'python3-pyqt4' for your distro/OS and/or version.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency. Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer

What do I have to do??

How are you installing drivers?  You might need hplip from the standard repositories and not a third party installation tool. That should be all you need to get the HP ENVY 6000 drivers into your system.
